# Repeated and Predictable RNG Values in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to generate 10,000 random numbers in a row in C and am having trouble getting random or even randomish results using the pseudo RNG. I used modulus in a way that I think should create uniformity, which it does, but the results are equivalent to 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3 etc. when run in a loop in another function calling RNG(4).

```
int RNG(int n) {
    int range = RAND_MAX - (RAND_MAX % n);
    srand(time(NULL));
    int x = rand();
    while (x > range) {
        x = rand();
    }
    return x % n;
}
```

Any way to get it closer to 1,3,2,0,2,3,1,0,0,3,2,0,1 etc. would be appreciated!

Thank you!

EDIT: Thanks for the responses everyone! Moved the seeding to the start of the function calling RNG and everything is dandy now!

Comment: 1. Choose whether you use `C` or `C++`.
2. If you've chosen `C++`, I have [some good news for you](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Comment: You are resetting the seed using `srand` every time you call `RNG`...

Comment: Stop resetting `srand()` in every loop.

Comment: If you want a *repeatable* sequence of pseudo-random numbers, call `srand()` (*once*) with a constant value, not with `time(NULL)`, which is designed to give you a new sequence every time it's run. Or don't all `srand()` at all, which is equivalent to calling `srand(1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not call `srand` every time you want to generate a number. `srand` initializes the pseudo-random number generator and is intended to be called just once at the start of your program, or when you want to reset the generator. By resetting it every time, you are forcing `rand` to generate the same numbers every time you call it within each second on the clock.

Do not use `x % n` to reduce the number to a desired range. Old implementations of `rand` are notoriously bad and have patterns in the low bits. Instead, use `x / ((RAND_MAX+1u) / n)`.

The code `int range = RAND_MAX - (RAND_MAX % n);` is flawed. Suppose `n` is 4 and `RAND_MAX` is 7, meaning `rand` returns 0 to 7. This code sets `range` to 4, and then `while (x > range) x = rand();` discards 5, 6, and 7, while it retains 4. There are two bugs here: The code keeps the five values 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4, which is a mismatch to (not a multiple of) the desired range of 4, and it unnecessarily discards values. If we had kept 4, 5, 6, and 7, we would have a match. You could use:

```
unsigned range = (RAND_MAX + 1u) - ((RAND_MAX + 1u) % n);
```

and:

```
while (x >= range) x = rand();
```

If you are using C++, switch to using [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). If you are using C, check the quality of `rand` in your implementation or switch to another generator such as the POSIX `srandom` and `random`.

Comment: I'm going to be snarky but... I guess this warrants a mention of https://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 0):

As noted elsewhere, the fix to the repeated numbers is to move the call to `srand(time(NULL))` outside this function and call it only once per program at the beginning.

As for why you're getting repeated numbers: The function is being called several times per second.  Each time the function executes in a given second, `time(NULL)` returns the same number, which this code uses to seed the random number generator.

The sequence of random numbers generated from a particular seed will always be the same.  This code takes the first number from that sequence, which is always the same for one second, until `time(NULL)` returns a new value.